# Trigger metamask popup to send ERC20

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets, walletconnect

Is there a way to trigger the metamask popup to send tokens with a specific token pre-selected but no amount/destination address set yet?

I.e. I don't want to initiate a full transfer yet through `contract.transfer.getData(destinationAddress, amount)` but just provide a good UX by having a button that says "Send SomeERC20" which would bring the user directly to the metamask "Add recipient" step (skipping asset selection and "send").

Comment: It can't be done

Comment: I which this was possible too.